# Error Code = 1117

Tags: windows-7, windows

I'm trying to system repair using ACER Recovery Disk but I keep getting Error Code = 1117.

Also, I've tried system restore using the same ACER Recovery Disk but I keep getting Error Code = 1117.

What do I need to do.

Comment: Hello Neil, please give as many information as you can like your operating system and hardware specs. At what state of the recovery procedure you will get that error? Also very useful are little screenshots which shows your error. (only if its possible)

Comment: Error 1117 = ERROR_IO_DEVICE (The request could not be performed because of an I/O device error.) Maybe the DVD drive is bad.

Answer (score 0):

The question is **What do I need to do.**

As mentioned in the comments Error 1117 is an I/O Device Error, your Hard Drive may have failed; I would recommend you download the [Ultmate Boot CD](http://www.ultimatebootcd.com/) and check your Hard Drive and devices, if you are unsure what this too is, and how to use it look [here](http://www.ehow.co.uk/how_2324170_use-ultimate-boot-cd-fix.html) for some instructions.